# Vb.net Get Custom Uri Protocol Parameters & Parse

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have searched a lot here on stackoverflow and googled as well but haven't find any working solution and i am a newbie btw.
I have a windows forms based application. I can launch it by custom Url Protocol `myapp://` by Setting a Registery Key:

```
My App > shell > command > pathtomyfile/app.exe
```

I have added a hyperlink to launch application i.e

```
myapp://test123
```

and it launched app.exe just fine. Now how can i recieve the test123 as arguments.

So my question is:

How do I receive the `test123` as a parameter in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
For Each argument As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
    ... (Add code here to use the argument) 
Next
```

You can use this i.e. in Form1.Load or Form1.Shown event.